# top 5 or N lists from nested lists "using one of the element" from nested list (little bit complex)

Tags: list, python-2.7, nested-lists

I have list like following

```
m=[['abc','x-name',222],['pqr','y-name',333],['mno','j-name',333],['qrt','z-name',111],['dcu','lz-name',999]]
```

Let's say I want to get top 2 out of this list considering 3rd column(i.e 222 or etc)

I know I can get the Max one like following

```
>>> m=[['abc','x-name',222],['pqr','y-name',333],['mno','j-name',333],['qrt','z-name',111],['dcu','lz-name',999]]
>>> print max(m, key=lambda x: x[2])
['dcu', 'lz-name', 999]
```

but what I have to get top 2 (considering the duplicates) my result should be

```
['dcu', 'lz-name', 999] ['pqr','y-name',333] ['mno','j-name',333]
```

Is it possible? I head is spinning trying to figure it out, can you pls have look and help me..

**OR -just got idea**

You can tell me to delete MAX element so that I can get top 2 elements using iteration( duplicate will be a problem though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *sort and slice* instead:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(m, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)[:3]
[['dcu', 'lz-name', 999], ['pqr', 'y-name', 333], ['mno', 'j-name', 333]]
```

Or, using the [`heapq.nlargest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
>>> import heapq
>>> heapq.nlargest(3, m, key=itemgetter(2))
[['dcu', 'lz-name', 999], ['pqr', 'y-name', 333], ['mno', 'j-name', 333]]
```

This, though, would not handle the duplicates nicely and it is not of a linear time complexity, plus it would created a sorted copy of the initial list in memory. Please see the following threads for linear-time and more memory-efficient solutions:

- [Get the second largest number in a list in linear time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225677/get-the-second-largest-number-in-a-list-in-linear-time)
- [Best way to sort 1M records in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180240/best-way-to-sort-1m-records-in-python)

Comment: Actually my list is too big 10Meg to 100 meg around, will sorting be a good idea?

Comment: So alecxe,just to be clear, do you say, I should be going with sorted()?

Comment: @Manojcode I would experiment with the linear-time solutions that would not produce an extra list in memory more, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16226255/771848). Plus, the sample solutions I've posted don't handle the duplicates...not sure how strict of a requirement it is. Thanks.

Comment: In terms of requirements, i could not skip any data. But What I am seeing is both approaches are handling duplicates pretty fine as it sorts the list first and I take top 5 which is pretty much I need, but still complexity perspective, I am not sure if there is any other solution to this..